# How can I print the subject of a text

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

Im using this code to determine what the subject, and time/location of a sentence.

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk

text = input('Please enter a sentence: ')
words = text.split()
sentence = pos_tag(words)

grammar = '''
Action: {<NN.*>?<VB.*><RB.*>?}
Location: {<IN><NN.*>+}
Subject: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN.*>}
'''
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar, "Input")
result = cp.parse(sentence)

result.draw()
```

How can i print just the subject of the sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "label" attribute the Tree objects. Here I set up a loop to check each element of the result to see if it is a nltk.tree.Tree instance. Then, if the label is "Subject", it gets appended t

```
subject = []
for word in result:
    print word
    if isinstance(word, nltk.tree.Tree):
        if word.label() == 'Subject':
            subject.append(word)

# Sentence returned multiple subjects, including direct object, so draw first one
subject[0].draw()
```

Of course, this assumes that whatever is labeled "Subject" is what you want to draw.